# Count active boxes in the rack from transaction logs

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have 2 tables here

1. Rack

| Id | RackName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Rack A |
| 2 | Rack B |

2. RackTransaction

| Id | RackId | Barcode | Event | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ABC1234 | IN | 2021-07-12 |
| 2 | 1 | ABC1234 | OUT | 2021-07-20 |
| 3 | 1 | ABC1235 | IN | 2021-07-21 |
| 4 | 1 | ABC1236 | IN | 2021-07-21 |
| 5 | 1 | ABC1236 | OUT | 2021-07-23 |
| 6 | 1 | ABC1237 | IN | 2021-07-21 |
| 7 | 1 | ABC1238 | IN | 2021-07-21 |
| 8 | 1 | ABC1238 | OUT | 2021-07-23 |

Barcode `ABC1235` and `ABC1237` not check out yet. So the total count boxes inside the `RACK A` is 2.

So from given sample data, how I can generate using the linq?

```
var getTotal = await _context.RackBoxLogs.Where(c => c.RackId == rackId)
                                .GroupBy(c => new { c.Barcode,c.Event })
                                .Select(g => new { g.Key, MaxDate = g.Max(c => c.CreatedOn),Event = g.Key.Event })
                                .Where(c=> c.Event == "IN")
                                .CountAsync();
```

Even I already group by the barcode and filter the max date I still get the wrong result.  Any idea?

Comment: What is `RackBoxLogs` and how does it relate to `Rack` and `RackTransaction`? Should `RackTransaction.Id` be unique?

Comment: BTW, what LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Hi, I am using EF Core 3.1 and PostgreSQL as database provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work with EF 5, I think. Unfortunately EF 5 can't (yet) translate `GroupBy().Select(g => g.Last())`.

```
var getTotal = RackTransaction
                .Where(rt => rt.RackId == rackId)
                .Select(rt => rt.Barcode)
                .Distinct()
                .Select(b => RackTransaction.Where(rt => rt.Barcode == b).OrderBy(rt => rt.DateTime).Last())
                .Where(rt => rt.Event == "IN")
                .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should get desired count:

```cs
var getTotal = await _context.RackBoxLogs
    .Where(c => c.RackId == rackId)
    .GroupBy(c => new { c.Barcode })
    .Where(g => g.Sum(x => x.Event == "IN"  ? 1 : 0) > 
                g.Sum(x => x.Event == "OUT" ? 1 : 0)
    )
    .CountAsync();
```